# как настроить фильтр для столбаца в excel через c#, возможно ли использовать для этого какую либо систему?

Tags: c#, excel

В архиве на стеллажах хранятся коробки с документами.
Каждый стеллаж имеет свой штрих-код – Sххххх, где х – цифра от 0 до 9
Каждая полка на стеллажах имеет свой штрих-код – Pххххх, где х – цифра от 0 до 9. Нумерация сквозная, т.е. у каждой полки свой уникальный штрих-код.
Каждая коробка имеет свой штрих-код – Kххххх, где х – цифра от 0 до 9. Нумерация сквозная, т.е. у каждой коробки свой уникальный штрих-код.
Данные о стеллажах, полках и коробках считываются штрихкодером в xls-файл, который имеет формат:
Sххххх
Pххххх
Kххххх
Kххххх
Kххххх
Kххххх
Sххххх
Pххххх
Kххххх
Sххххх
Pххххх
Kххххх
Kххххх
Pххххх 
Kххххх
Kххххх
(иначе говоря столбец в Excel) 
Порядок следования данных: сначала сканируется стеллаж, потом – полка, потом – коробки на полке. После того, как все коробки на полке отсканированы, переход к следующей полке, процесс повторяется. После сканирования всех полок – переход к следующему стеллажу.

у меня есть два вопроса:

1. возможно ли это каким либо образом реализовать через  с# ?
2. существуют ли системы которые могут обработать такой поток данных ?

Большое спасибо за потраченное время !

Стелаж меняется только в случае перехода к новому - иначе говоря S1P1K1K2K3 S2P2K4K5 вот пример [1drv.ms/f/s!AsSF97QkK8MmmE_HNaEWmg1zUH2Z](https://1drv.ms/f/s!AsSF97QkK8MmmE_HNaEWmg1zUH2Z)

Comment: Готовых не знаю, но наверняка есть и некастомизируемые программы и конструкторы сделай-сам, где интеграторы допилят за вас. При реализации я бы не закладывался на запись в эксельный файл, а сделал бы запись в базу данных, а уж из неё дал бы возможность выгружать в эксель. Вопрос ваш слишком широк для so, вряд ли тут найдёте подходящий ответ.

Comment: Что нужно-то? В заголовке - фильтрация, в тексте о фильтрации ни слова...Отсканировали  - дальше что? Или нужна реализация процесса сканирования и записи? Что подразумевается под обработкой потока данных?

Comment: @vikttur здравствуйте ! Спасибо за потраченное время ! Нужно добиться следующего: при вводе номера коробки система (чем бы она не была)должна выдавать номер полки и стеллажа где стоит коробка

Comment: Т.е. нужно обрабатывать не поток данных, а уже имеющийся столбец с данными? Искать в нем принадлежность указаной коробки? Это можно реализовать в самом  *Excel* простой формулой. Но по Вашим данным непонятно, как сформирован ряд: S1P1K1K2K3 S1P2K4K5 или S1P1K1K2K3 S2P2K4K5. Т.е. при изменении полки стеллаж не менять? Нумерация коробок сквозная для всех стеллажей или для одного? Уточните, отредактируйте вопрос и покажите пример  реальных оттсканированых данных.

Comment: Стелаж меняется только в случае перехода к новому - иначе говоря S1P1K1K2K3 S2P2K4K5 вот пример https://1drv.ms/f/s!AsSF97QkK8MmmE_HNaEWmg1zUH2Z Спасибо, что помогаете !